# Getting an ActorRef when a WebSocket is closed in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

According to the [Play framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets#detecting-when-a-websocket-has-closed), we have the option of overriding the `postStop` method, but it has no `ActorRef`. I need an `ActorRef` because I am using `ActorRef` as an identifier in a `HashMap` containing the mappings of actors to connected clients: on disconnect, I want to remove that mapping from the `HashMap`.

Edit:-
Here `HashMap` works as an authentication pool.The very first message from client is for Authentication, and on validation the instance of ActorRef is added to `HashMap`. On the following events/messages authorization is verified by checking the existence of `ActorRef` in `HashMap`, have a look at the following code:-

```
  def authenticate(actorRef: ActorRef, message: SocketParsedMessage) {
    (message.data \ "token").validate[String] match {
      case s: JsSuccess[String] => {
        val token = jwt.parse(s.get)
        if (jwt.verify(token,jwtSecret)) {
          val userId = UUID.fromString(jwt.getSubject(token))
          hashMapU2A += (UUID.fromString(jwt.getSubject(token)) -> actorRef)
          hashMapA2U += (actorRef -> userId)
          actorRef ! SocketParsedMessage(AllowedSocketMessageTypes.AUTHENTICATE, Json.obj(
            "success" -> true, "message" -> "Authorized for making further requests request")).toString
          publishUserStatus(userId)
        } else {
          actorRef ! SocketParsedMessage(AllowedSocketMessageTypes.AUTHENTICATE, JsObject(
            Seq("success" -> JsBoolean(false), "message" -> JsString("Invalid token"))
          )).toString
        }
      }
      case e: JsError => {
        actorRef ! SocketParsedMessage(AllowedSocketMessageTypes.AUTHENTICATE, Json.obj(
          "success" -> false, "message" -> "Token not supplied with request")).toString
        actorRef ! PoisonPill
      }
    }
  }



val hashMapA2U: mutable.HashMap[ActorRef, UUID] = mutable.HashMap()
```

Comment: The subscriber actor dies on an `onClose` Action. You won't have access to it anymore.. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RobertUdah I have implemented an websocket based user online/offline tracker. And I am using actorRef in HashMap for retrieving User ID of client connected.

Comment: You cannot change your ```HashMap[ActorRef, UUID]``` to ```HashMap[String, ActorRef`]``` ?

Comment: I can but How I will get that String, same question again.

Comment: I don't want to supply an authentication token every time with WebSocket Message /Event, because it will become headache to both client and server side. I have edited the question please look at that.

Answer (score 0):

My Stupidity.

Actually, ActorRef is already provided in my custom implementation of Actor, and I can use it.

```
class MyWebSocketActor(sh: HandleSocket, out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
      case msg: String => {
        Json.fromJson[SocketParsedMessage](Json.parse(msg)) match {
          case s: JsSuccess[SocketParsedMessage] => {
            sh.HandleSocketMessages(out, s.get)
          }
          case _: JsError => {
            out ! PoisonPill
          }
        }
        // println(parsedMsg)
        // out ! (msg)
      }
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    // super.postStop()
    sh.clientDisconnected(out)
  }
}
```